# Can't run script using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am able to connect to the DB using MySQL Workbench, but when I try to Run SQL Script I get the following error:

**Error executing SQL script. 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost'(using password: YES)**

I know there are a lot of questions with this problem, but I do not know if it is the same issue. I have no problem connecting and viewing tables etc...

Comment: `Access denied`, not much more to it then that. You have the wrong username / password.

Comment: @MattClark That is what I thought too, but for some reason I can connect to the DB using that User name and Password on Workbench. The error only shows when trying to run a script.

Comment: Look in the log of Workbench to see if there's more info. Also enable debug logging (in the preferences) to get more info logged.